Sticky navbar snap in place few pixels lower that it should be after smooth scrolling to section
i have a problem with a templat, on phone version, as the title says, every time i chick an , it scrolls to the specific section of the page but somehow it snaps few pixels under.
you can test it here: test.acwebsite.ro
you can also see the code with view source. the JS of the file is "site.js" and CSS is "style.css"
i tryed adding margins and/or paddings hopping to make the space between sections bigger but to no avail. it scrolls past the margins and padding at snaps at the same poin witch is a .
i also added another  above the  one and it seems to snap over the first element in the section.

Please provide the relevant code, otherwise, it has no usage for future readers, and it's also problematic to help you that way.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

I will post as soon as I can
